# How to access EntityDataSource selected data programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have created a EntityDataModel as follows:

[image]

And I have a user control in which I want to read data from database and write in my usercontrol but I don't want to write core ADO.NET code for doing it.

So I thought I can use EntityDataSource to do this.

This is my usercontrol:

[image]

I want to read table rows from database using EntityDataSource and put them in my usercontrol so I can save my time and work. but I don't know how to read data from EntityDataSource.

I have configured EntityDataSource control and connected it to the table I want but I don't know how to read data?

Edit: I use selected event and e.results but it does not work.
Selected event never rises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get access to result of query executed in EntityDataSource by handling its [Selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) event and accessing Results of EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs.

Comment: Selected event never rises

Comment: What is the return type of e.results and when it rises?

Comment: objects returned by the query

Comment: Selected event does not raise

Comment: Add this statement in your code protected void NameofSource_OnSelected(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e)
{
   
}

Comment: I do but it does not work- i set a breakpoint to debug onSelected method but it does not raise

Comment: <asp:EntityDataSource OnSelected="EventHandler" />

Comment: refer this link for more detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.selected(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks but the event never occurs.i configure entitydatasource in design time

Comment: why this event never raises?